# File creation failing in Perl

Tags: perl, unix, file-permissions

My code is failing at below point

```
my $filePath = '/opt/CUSTOM/PREPRD/IP/actions/file.conf';
my $udf;
if (-e $filePath){
  open $udf, "<", $filePath or die $!;
}
else{
  open $udf, ">", $filePath or die $!;
}
```

The file doesn't exists and code fails in first iteration. I would have expected the first block to work.

Comment: Failing how? You are dying with `$!`, what does it say?

Comment: Did you make sure you have the right permissions?

Comment: i changed the path to /tmp/file.conf and it worked ,,,,,,but i want this to be in the same directory what should be the permissions on flders , all the folder have 755 permission @Cahu

Comment: This code looks OK, unless the first `open` is failing because of a permissions problem. Are you clear that the `$udf` file handle will be opened *either* for read *or* for write, depending on whether the file existed or not? That means you can either print to the file handle or read from it, but you will have to write further `if` statements to discover which. I think it's more likely that you want just an open for write (the second `open` statement) or perhaps for append (with a mode of `'>>'`).

Comment: @Quentin   Error `No such file or directory at createUserDefinedConnections.pl`

Comment: @Borodin the file doesnt exist in first iteration and it goes to else block and fails , beleive it is permission issue , but i have 755 set on all folders, what should be the permission on folder

Comment: @learner you need write permission to the folder in order to be allowed to create the file in the `else` block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is most likely that the path to your file doesn't exist. Use [`File::Path`](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aPath) with [`File::Basename`](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aBasename) to create any missing intermediate directories, like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Path 'make_path';
use File::Basename 'dirname';

my $filePath = '/opt/CUSTOM/PREPRD/IP/actions/file.conf';

make_path dirname $filePath;

my $udf;
if (-e $filePath) {
  open $udf, '<', $filePath or die "Unable to open conf file for input: $!"
}
else {
  open $udf, '>', $filePath or die "Unable to open conf file for output: $!"
}
```

Please note that after this code you can *either* read from the `$udf` file handle *or* print to it, and it will be difficult to tell which.

Comment: got the file path wrong but this is some good stuff i would want to use

Comment: What do you mean *“got the file path wrong”*? This is copied from your own code.

Comment: Ah okay. Calling `make_path` will do that for you. That is the point of my answer. If you have the solution you needed then please mark your problem as being solved by accepting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
use File::Path;#abs_path, mkpath
use File::Basename;#dirname

unless($> == 0){
# are you root :: you need to be root to do write into /opt/... 
    $0 = Cwd::abs_path($0);
    system ("sudo $0");
    `sudo -K`;
    exit;
}

my $filePath = '/opt/CUSTOM/PREPRD/IP/actions/file.conf';
my $udf;
if (-e $filePath){
  open $udf, "<", $filePath or die $!;
}
else{
  $path = dirname($filepath);
  File::Path::mkpath($path);

  open $udf, ">", $filePath or die $!;
}
```